# I want to set an onClick listener for custom view in sketchware

Tags: sketchware

{`final Button tab3button2 = view findViewById(R.id.button2); View.OnClickListener() { @Override pubilc void onClick (View v)`

I have tried searching for answers but all to no avail.

Comment: Could you give more detail about what you want to do exactly and more detail on the context

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the code for on click on source code, and you must have a section like bindview or webview to get at the id of widget. Then just enter I'd, make sure it's different then all others on same page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need, I edited your code:

```
final Button tab3button2 = view findViewById(R.id.button2);
tab3button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View _view) {
```

`here put the blocks that will be executed when the button gets clicked`

```
    }
});
```

it's recommended to add this code in the `onCreate` event, but if this `Button` is in a `ListView` custom view then add it in the `onBindCustomView` event.